What was the punishment in the City of Judgement under Jergal's rule?
In the Forgotten Realms, the souls of recently departed wait on the Fugue Plane to be picked up and taken to whatever paradise they believed in by avatars of their gods. But those that were either False (betrayed their god) or Faithless (never believed in one) are instead taken to the City at the centre of this realm, where the God of Death passes his judgement over them.
With Kelemvor as the ruler, this place is called the City of Judgement and the punishment is usually (at least for the False)  eternity without any joy. Under Cyric the Mad, the city was called the "City of Strife" and it was a giant torture chamber both for the usual victims as well as for Cyric's faithful.
I don't know much about the rule of Myrkul, but judging by his penchant for necromancy, it wouldn't be hard to believe that the "City of the Dead" was exactly that - a city full of ever-loyal wraiths and walking corpses. I know that it was Myrkul who created the infamous "Wall of the Faithless", built from the souls of those who never worshipped anyone.
But even before Myrkul, there was Jergal - one of the ancient gods, the "Lord of the End of Everything". Do we know what the City was like under his rule?

We really only know only one thing about the City under Jergal's rule
...which is that it didn't have a Wall of the Faithless. As best as is documented, Myrkul put that up when he started sorting the Faithless and the False. He did always like terrorizing mortals with the fear of death in all its myriad flavors. Jergal was described as ruling over "a kingdom unchallenged by any other god" (Faiths & Avatars) from his Castle of Bone, a "shadowy kingdom of endless gloom". It was chock-full of undead, entire legions from the corporeal to the incorporeal, so many that Jergal had spare liches whose skulls could be used for bowling.
If you'd like additional conjecture...
...then I touched on this previously. In brief, Jergal didn't want or need some kind of dedicated punishment for the souls under his charge. He ruled a nightmarish kingdom of death and gloom, it was all the up-jumped mortals who felt like it had to do something besides just be a vast necropolis lorded over by a living nightmare.
